# Adding forms to individual entries where only one or two questions change

Tags: add-on, forms

A client has requested setting up a channel where they can add forms associated with each entry.

At first Forms from DevDemon looked like a good fit as it has a fieldtype to enable this, but in my case, the forms will be nearly the same for every entry except for one or two questions. For example, every form will capture name, email and phone, but then there will be one or two questions unique to that entry.

So really I need to either be able to save a form for reuse for each entry which can then be modified to include the unique questions, or have a way of defining certain default inputs that apply to every form, and then when the client creates a new form in the CP, the new questions get added to the default set.

Currently it doesn't seem like Forms can do this (saved forms is a feature that may be introduced later) so I'm wondering if there's a way to do this with one of the other forms add-ons?

Or maybe another creative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else following along, it looks like you can do exactly what I want with http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/proform-catchall

Comment: Yep, I created Catchall for exactly this purpose in ProForm. It's fairly simple to use a Matrix or other source of question text to populate the questions that will be fed into Catchall.

Answer (score 2):

What about taking a hybrid approach using FreeForm?

Add a matrix to your channel and allow the editor to define the custom fields. You'd want columns for field labels and field type (dropdown, text, etc) and possibly a third for field options.

Your template will hard code the fields that are common to all forms and loop through the matrix to generate the custom fields.

[This article goes into more detail.](http://trevordavis.net/blog/freeform-fieldframe-expressionengine-form-builder) It's from EE 1.x but the same principles apply.

Also, [this article](http://focuslabllc.com/blog/form-building-add-ons-in-expressionengine) has a nice round up of EE2 form addons.

Comment: Seems like Trevor's approach would be similar to if I used the current Freeform Pro. You first have to create the fields you'd use inside the Freeform module, then go to your entry to add the form. Which would work, but it's not ideal as it means having to do work in two places to achieve a single result.